# Checking for the latest version of a contract in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

First stackoverflow question, so hopefully I've done this correctly! I've had a good look on various sites ranging from Mr XL to Chandoo, and a good look on here too, and I've not come up with a solution yet.

I've got a spreadsheet which tracks contracts, but I need to know if its the latest version. I've tried the If(Max) formula I've seen suggested to no avail.

This is what I've got so far and its not working!

Example:

```
   Contract Number     Version               - Latest Version

    12345                 1                    =IF(B2=(MAX(A:A=A2,B:B)),"Yes","No")
    12345                 2
```

Is this something I'd have to VBA up a solution for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were close, but not quite, with the [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=IF(B2=MAX(IF(A2=A:A,B:B)),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thanks Aprillion - Its still not quite working for me. Will this formula change if the contract number has letters in as well? - for example if it's 1-2ABC4D5

Comment: no, have you entered the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Comment: No, just copy pasted the formula into excel, and changed the references to be correct for my spreadsheet - in my spreadsheet the contract number is in column D, and version in column E - so I've got '=if(e2=max(if(d2=d:d,E:e)),"Yes","No")'

Comment: then please do confirm your adjusted formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of plain Enter - I added a link to official guidelines about array formulas in my answer, you might want to have a look

Comment: Legendary, Didn't know about that Aprillion, thank you very much for your help.